# Error when using jsconfig in .NET Core w/ React

Tags: reactjs, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, vscode-jsconfig

I am trying to add a jsconfig file to my .NET Core with React App, but it has been failing when launching the app. When launching the app I am getting the following repeated error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyMiddleware: Information: SPA proxy is not ready. Returning temporary landing page.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyLaunchManager: Error: Couldn't start the SPA development server with command 'npm start'.
```

The jsconfig file is placed in the Client App folder and has the following contents at the moment:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "jsx": "react",
        "paths": {
            "@components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
            "@constants/*": ["./src/consts/*"],
            "@images/*": ["./src/images/*"],
            "@pages/*": ["./src/pages/*"],
        }
    },
    "exclude": [
        "Constants",
        "Controllers",
        "DataServices",
        "Models",
        "Pages",
        "Properties",
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.js",
        "src/**/*.jsx",
    ]
}
```

If I remove the file entirely, everything runs fine, could someone please assist in this issue?

Comment: adding jsconfig file won't cause a startup issue, I copy & paste your content into my project and my project can start as usual. I'm afraid it's because some conflict. Maybe you can try to commemt some parts of the content and see if the project can start. For example, comment all the content inside jsconfig file first and clean and start the project.

Comment: Tried that, but am still having the issue, I can put a blank jsconfig file in the ClientApp folder and still have the same issue